# each() inside function() and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this, each

Lets say this is our function:

```
$('ul li').bind('click', function(){

   $('iframe').each(function(){
        // who is this???
        alert(this);
   });

});
```

As you can see, there is an .each() sentence that is using `$(this)` inside,

What element will be referenced by `$(this)` ??? `ul li`? or `iframe`? I'm trying, as you can guess, to select each iframe (in the  webpage, nothin to do with ul li, there)

I ask this because i am getting unexpected results with a way larger function,

Comment: No doubt it would be an iframe. COuld you be more specific about the "way larger function" and these "unexpected results"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the object of the most specific function scope.

```
$('ul li').bind('click', function(){

    // this = [ul li]

    $('iframe').each(function(){

        // this = [iframe]

    });
});
```

If you want to reference the the `ul li` version of `this` from inside the `iframe` inner function, you would have to form a closure around it, like the following:

```
$('ul li').bind('click', function () {
    // cache this
    var that = this;

    $('iframe').each(function () {

        // here, this = [iframe] and
        //       that = [ul li]

    });
});
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, you might want to use `var that` (or `$that` for jQ).

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/each/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
   $('li').each(function(index) {
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
      });
```

Alert output:

**0: foo**

**1: bar**

`this` will refer to the `iframe` objects. 
The above code is taken from the jQuery documentation.

You might want to tell us what the expected results, and maybe post the whole code here.

Comment: is not the same case,because here the .each is not inside a function

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet It is the same.  The link provided by Kemal shows examples of `each` being run inside a `click` handler, just like your question.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to iframe u can check it from here http://jsfiddle.net/x2XyU/1/

Comment: haha, that was quick to proove! but check this out http://jsfiddle.net/x2XyU/2/ why is undefined? shouldn't be <li> ??

Comment: hahaha, u dont know how to use tagName check this out http://jsfiddle.net/x2XyU/3/